# Is it a good way store photo sets in a djvu file?

Tags: file-format

I have many set photos and i need organize them in packages, albums, something like that. I was storing them in a zip or cbz file, but djvu files seems best.

What do you think about?

Answer (score 3):

That seems terrible to me. Djvu is a format designed for *scanned documents*, not for photographs. It has features that are great for that — like separation of text from the background — but which are useless for photographs. And it *doesn't* have any particular features which make it good for photography. It uses a wavelet compression algorithm, which is generally good and probably better than that used for JPEG, but if your photos are *already* JPEGs then you're just introducing double compression artifacts. The only reason to do this would be if space is at a premium over quality.

I think your reasonable options are:

1. Store in a filesystem with subdirectories.
2. Use a program with photograph cataloging features, like Adobe Lightroom.
3. Use a sophisticated digital content management system like Dspace.

You could use archive files like zip, but I don't see any particular advantage in doing so unless you need to give them to other people on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store multiple photographs in a single file for reference or similar purposes (Location scouting archive etc.) without sacrificing the ability to inspect EXIF information, cbz and cbr will be the quickest and least complicated solutions as they are nothing more than zip and rar files with their respective file extensions changed to cbz and cbr. There are cbz and cbr readers on android and ios as well as linux, mac and windows.

For presentation purposes, PDF files provide you with the best options regarding distribution and printing etc. control - you can restrict or allow whatever you need.

None of these are good for archival as cbz/cbr do not offer thumbnails - there are no gains from compression with photos, so you would probably benefit the most from some cataloguing software instead...